# Decoding JSON with Python and storing nested object

Tags: python, json

I am trying to decode the following JSON file with Python:

```
{"node":[
    {
    "id":"12387",
    "ip":"172.20.0.1",
    "hid":"213", 
    "coord":{"dist":"12","lat":"-9.8257","lon":"65.0880"},
    "status":{"speed":"90","direction":"N"},
    "ts":"12387"}
]
}
```

By using:

```
json_data=open('sampleJSON')
jdata = json.load(json_data)
for key, value in jdata.iteritems():
    print "Key:"
    print key
    print "Value:"
    print value
```

and i have as output:

```
Key:
node
Value:
[{u'status': {u'direction': u'N', u'speed': u'90'}, u'ip': u'172.20.0.1', u'ts': u'12387', u'coord': {u'lat': u'-9.8257', u'lon': u'65.0880', u'dist': u'12'}, u'hid': u'213', u'id': u'12387'}]
```

And i want to be able to print the key's and values of the nested objects **status**, **coord**, and also que key/values of **node**, "hid", "id", "ip" and "ts".

How can i interate throughout all the nested values?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to print it all out.  This could be improved, but here is the idea:

```
import json

json_data = open('data.json')
jdata = json.load(json_data)

def printKeyVals(data, indent=0):
    if isinstance(data, list):
        print
        for item in data:
            printKeyVals(item, indent+1)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        print
        for k, v in data.iteritems():
            print "    " * indent, k + ":",
            printKeyVals(v, indent + 1)
    else:
        print data
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 node:

         status:
             direction: N
             speed: 90
         ip: 172.20.0.1
         ts: 12387
         coord:
             lat: -9.8257
             lon: 65.0880
             dist: 12
         hid: 213
         id: 12387
```

Otherwise, you could just use:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(jdata)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it totally nailed it

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your specific use case, it's hard to give a general answer, but..

If you have an arbitrarily nested structure, this is a good case for recursion.

simple sample code:

```
def print_object(object, indent=0):
    if type(object)==dict:
        for key, value in object.iteritems():
            print " "*4*indent, "Key: ", key
            print " "*4*indent, "Value: "
            print_object(value, indent+1)
    elif type(object)==list:
        for value in object:
            print_object(value,indent+1)
    else:
        print " "*4*indent, object
```

you really don't want to do strict type checking, but it works for quick-and-dirty sample code.

output:

```
 Key:  node
 Value: 
         Key:  status
         Value: 
             Key:  direction
             Value: 
                 N
             Key:  speed
             Value: 
                 90
         Key:  ip
         Value: 
             172.20.0.1
         Key:  ts
         Value: 
             12387
         Key:  coord
         Value: 
             Key:  lat
             Value: 
                 -9.8257
             Key:  lon
             Value: 
                 65.0880
             Key:  dist
             Value: 
                 12
         Key:  hid
         Value: 
             213
         Key:  id
         Value: 
             12387
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the top level element of your JSON is a dictionary containing a list of dictionaries. If you want to keep this structure, try the code below.

```
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('sampleJSON')
jdata = json.load(json_data)
node = jdata['node'][0]

for key, value in node.iteritems():
    pprint("Key:")
    pprint(key)
    pprint("Value:")
    pprint(value)
```